# Which points are decisive in the "Oriented Minimum Bounding Box" algorithm in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, extents

I used the ombb algorithm in QGIS and there were no problems with it. I am just wondering which points determine / influence the angle, how the orientation of the box is determined and when a box is inclined by more than 90 ° or less than 90 °. The documentation doesn't help me.

In ArcGIS there is the function "CalculatePolygonMainAngle" and I think that the angle of the ombb can vary a lot from the ArcGIS function. I don't have ArcGIS and unfortunately I can't try it out.

Comment: Your second sentence doesn't really make sense. Could you edit your question to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt check the [code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/core/geometry/qgsinternalgeometryengine.cpp#L1452) the answer seems to be that only points on the convex hull are used in the calculation and all those points are considered in turn:

```
QgsGeometry QgsInternalGeometryEngine::orientedMinimumBoundingBox( double &area, double &angle, double &width, double &height ) const
{
  mLastError.clear();

  QgsRectangle minRect;
  area = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
  angle = 0;
  width = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
  height = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();

  if ( !mGeometry || mGeometry->nCoordinates() < 2 )
    return QgsGeometry();

  std::unique_ptr< QgsGeometryEngine >engine( QgsGeometry::createGeometryEngine( mGeometry ) );
  QString error;
  std::unique_ptr< QgsAbstractGeometry > hull( engine->convexHull( &mLastError ) );
  if ( !hull )
    return QgsGeometry();

  QgsVertexId vertexId;
  QgsPoint pt0;
  QgsPoint pt1;
  QgsPoint pt2;
  // get first point
  hull->nextVertex( vertexId, pt0 );
  pt1 = pt0;
  double totalRotation = 0;
  while ( hull->nextVertex( vertexId, pt2 ) )
  {
    double currentAngle = QgsGeometryUtils::lineAngle( pt1.x(), pt1.y(), pt2.x(), pt2.y() );
    double rotateAngle = 180.0 / M_PI * currentAngle;
    totalRotation += rotateAngle;

    QTransform t = QTransform::fromTranslate( pt0.x(), pt0.y() );
    t.rotate( rotateAngle );
    t.translate( -pt0.x(), -pt0.y() );

    hull->transform( t );

    QgsRectangle bounds = hull->boundingBox();
    double currentArea = bounds.width() * bounds.height();
    if ( currentArea  < area )
    {
      minRect = bounds;
      area = currentArea;
      angle = totalRotation;
      width = bounds.width();
      height = bounds.height();
    }

    pt1 = hull->vertexAt( vertexId );
  }
  // constrain angle to 0 - 180
  if ( angle > 180.0 )
    angle = std::fmod( angle, 180.0 );

  return minBounds;
}
  // constrain angle to 0 - 180
  if ( angle > 180.0 )
    angle = std::fmod( angle, 180.0 );

  return minBounds;
}
```